# Change Wordpress "Update Shopping Cart" Button Text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

Current button says "update shopping bag", I'm trying to figure out how to make it say "update shopping cart". This button is seen in-cart, when an item is in the cart.

I managed to change all the other buttons that said "Add to Bag" to "Add to Cart", but this one is tripping me up.

Does anybody know how to do this in woo commerce?

http://montagewestport.com

Comment: have you changed it from `.po`file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text is set in the `cart.php` file in the `yourtheme/woocommerce/cart` folder. It is on line ~ 160

```
        <input type="submit" class="update-button button" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e('Update Shopping Bag', 'theretailer'); ?>" />
```

Changing the `Update Shopping Bag` to `Update shopping cart` should change it for you.

Comment: It already reads "Update Cart" in that file.  It must be getting overridden somewhere? But I am no sure where.

Comment: Do you have ftp access to your site?

Comment: Yes, not sure if I should post info publicly.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not going to ask for the details. If you download a copy of the theme and if you have a program like notepad++ or textpad, you can use one of those programs to search a folder. You could use one of them to search folder for an occurrence of "Add to Bag" text.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can search a whole folder for text. I'll try that.